# Value returns wrong value

Tags: c, function, pointers, return

I am creating a function that takes an individuals record (stored in `*individual` in the function parameters), separates the record in order to get the persons birthday, and then the function calculates their age.  The problem I am encountering is when I use `strrchr` to search the record for the birthday, it changes the original value when I don't want it to.  So, instead of storing `Steven, Cortright, 3/1/1940` like it should, it stores `Steven, Cortright, 3`

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this.  below is my code I appreciate any help/advice:

```
char* calcage(char *individual)
  {

    time_t current_time;
    char *c_time_string;
    char *birthday;
    char *bmonth, *bday, *byear;
    int numbmonth, numbday,  numbyear;
    struct tm str_bday;
    time_t time_bday;
    double diff;
    double years;

    double monthscalc;
    int monthsage;
    int yearsage;


    current_time = time(NULL);


    c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);
    birthday = strrchr(individual, ',');
    birthday++;


    bmonth = strtok(birthday, "/");
    bday = strtok(NULL, "/");
    byear = strtok(NULL, "/");

    numbmonth = atoi(bmonth);
    numbday = atoi(bday);
    numbyear = atoi(byear);

    str_bday.tm_year = numbyear - 1900;
    str_bday.tm_mon = numbmonth - 1;
    str_bday.tm_mday = numbday;
    str_bday.tm_hour = 0;
    str_bday.tm_min = 0;
    str_bday.tm_sec = 1;
    time_bday = mktime(&str_bday);

    diff = difftime(current_time, time_bday);
    years = diff / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.242;

    yearsage = (int) years;


    int inpart = (int) years;
    double months = years - inpart;
    monthscalc = (365.242 * months) / 30.4368;

    monthsage = (int) monthscalc;

    char *calculatedAge = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    snprintf(calculatedAge,100,  "You are %d years and %d months old.", yearsage, \
    monthsage);

    return calculatedAge;
  }
```

Comment: This is due to strtok which modifies its argument as described in the docs

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `strtok`, not `strrchr`. `strtok` puts a null byte after the token *in the original buffer*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of strtok use sscanf to parse the string:

```
int month = 0, day = 0, year = 0;
sscanf( birthday, "%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year );
```

that way you don't mess up the argument

Answer (score 0):

```
char* calcage(char *individual){
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *local = localtime(&now);

    char *temp = strdup(strrchr(individual, ',')+1);//make copy
    char *birthday = temp;
    int bmonth, bday, byear;
    bmonth = atoi(strtok(temp, "/"));
    bday   = atoi(strtok(NULL, "/"));
    byear   = atoi(strtok(NULL, "/"));
    int age = local->tm_year + 1900 - byear -1;
    int lm = local->tm_mon + 1;
    if(bmonth <= lm && bday <= local->tm_mday)
        ++age;
    int mtemp = lm - bmonth;
    if(mtemp < 0 || mtemp == 0 && bday > local->tm_mday)
        mtemp += 12;
    int mage = age * 12 + mtemp;
    char *calculatedAge = realloc(temp, 50);
    snprintf(calculatedAge, 50, "You are %d years and %d months old.", age, mage);
    return calculatedAge;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.  When I tried to copy it before I posted on here, iI tried using strcpy, didn't know about strdup.  Thank you for your help